# How to check if SQL Server 2008 R2 database exists using power shell

Tags: sql, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a script for a database which works perfectly, however I ran into a problem where I need an `if` statement which checks if the database specified by user already exists. If it does, then the script should create a backup of it, if it does not exist, then the script should show an error.

Here is my script

```
#Loads Assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-
Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"
$bkdir = "C:\DBbackups" #We define the folder path as a variable 
$database = Read-Host "Please Specify Database Name"
$dbs = $server.Databases

#To Backup one Database specify exact name
#To backup multiple database which starts with same name use "*" 
foreach ($db in $dbs) 
{
 if($db.Name -like $database) 
 {
 $dbname = $db.Name
 $dt = get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss #We use this to create a file name based on the timestamp
 $dbBackup = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
 $dbBackup.Action = "Database"
 $dbBackup.Database = $dbname
 $dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice($bkdir + "\" + $dbname + "_db_" + $dt + ".bak", "File")
 $dbBackup.SqlBackup($server) 
 write-host "Database backup is successful for"$dbname
 write-host "."
 write-host "New Backup file is"$dbname"_db_"$dt".bak"
 }
 }

 write-host "New Backup Location is" $bkdir
```

This is what i have modified to

```
 foreach ($db in $dbs) 
{


 if($db.Name -like $database) 
 {
 $dbname = $db.Name
 $dt = get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss #We use this to create a file name based on the timestamp
 $dbBackup = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
 $dbBackup.Action = "Database"
 $dbBackup.Database = $dbname
 $dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice($bkdir + "\" + $dbname + "_db_" + $dt + ".bak", "File")
 $dbBackup.SqlBackup($server) 
 write-host "Database backup is successful for"$dbname `n

 write-host "New Backup file is"$dbname"_db_"$dt".bak" `n

 }
else {
write-host "invalid"
}
}
```

Comment: i am using sql server 2008 r2

Comment: can any one help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an else to the if ($db.Name -like $database) block

```
if ($db.Name -like $database) { # do current backup stuff }
else { write-output "Database doesn't exist" }
```

Comment: this isnt working, because i have a for loop and i get 8 or 9 times  displayed invalid database

Comment: This is done if i use this line at the top of for loop it worked for me ...if ($dbs.Name -like $database) {do backup}